# Can't prevent margins from collapsing

Tags: css

I had to to let a hover div menu get out of its container, so I declared that container with overflow: visible and it works, but now that container has lost its margin-bottom with the rest of the following in the list.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737799/vertical-margins-disappear-when-parent-is-set-to-overflowvisible) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828804/how-do-i-uncollapse-a-margin), as well as read a few other articles, and have tried putting paddings and the html code referenced on different elements, but I can't get what is going wrong in my specific case.

The url is http://melopienso.com/testingtwo/shop/ and each "ul.products li" should be having the bottom margin.

Any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element you want the `margin-bottom` on are floated. Therefore they don't extend their parent's height. so if you aply the margin on the parent, it will be "under" the floated elements.

**Explanation for your case :**

In your example `li.product` has 2 children : `a` and `gk-columns` . `.gk-columns` has only floated children so its height is 0 because floated elements don't extend parent's height. Therefore the height of `li.product` is only extended by the `a` tag which is 28px.

So if you aply `margin-bottom:50px;` on `li.product` it will push the content only of

```
28px + 50px = 78px
```

which is less than the height of the floated div.

You can solve this with several solutions :

**solution 1**
add the `margin-bottom` on the floated elements like this for your example :

```
.gk-columns>div{
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

**Solution 2**
if the height of the children elements is fixed set the height to the parent element so it covers the height of the floated children like this for you example :

```
.gk-columns{
    height:159px;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it works, although I don't quite get why. The element I'm trying to put the margin-bottom is "ul.products > li", and that element has "overflow: visible" but it is not floated (at least checking Chrome's computed styles). I'd appreciate if you could clarify that doubt. And thanks a lot!

Comment: It is GREAT. Thank you so much, it's been very very useful. Would this all be easier if I used "inline-block" for the .gk-columns children instead of floated elements ?