# margin-top does not work properly

Tags: html, css

I just can't find the issue with this script: http://jsfiddle.net/AKB3d/

```
#second {
  margin-top:50px;
  ...
}
```

I want the yellow box to be 50px below the top border of the right box, but whenever I add
margin-top to the yellow box, the red box goes down, too. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an `overflow:hidden` to the parent div, ie `#first`

This happens because of collapsing margins. [Vertical margins disappear when parent is set to overflow:visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737799/vertical-margins-disappear-when-parent-is-set-to-overflowvisible)

Comment: collapsing margins can be triggered with a border or a padding on the red box too , so it keeps it inside. just as a reminder :) http://jsfiddle.net/AKB3d/3/ and background-clip not too mess with borders http://jsfiddle.net/AKB3d/4/

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKB3d/1/)

```
#first {
margin:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
overflow:hidden;
}
```